# Would this patent prevent a patent of the same type of product made from a different material? Would that be considered a variation of this patent?

Tags: patentability, freedom-to-operate

In reference to the patent: [US5265515](https://www.google.com/patents/US5265515)

Comment: It has lapsed and is not a design patents

Answer (score 1):

The cited patent has expired. Thus, it does not inhibit you from making a product as specified in its claims. Whether you can obtain a patent for the same device with a different material is harder to assess. The challenge is obviousness. Would someone knowledgeable in the field think it an obvious substitution? My guess is that if you are simply changing one plastic with a similar one not mentioned in the patent it wouldn't be patentable. If however there were some unexpected benefit then it might be. It should be pointed out that there is every possibility that there are other patents or prior art that may impact the evaluation of patentability.